# kubernetes application pod is not able to share pod emptydir volume mount to daemonset fluentd pod

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

I have a application pod where I am logging log messed to a file a specific location.

I have already shared this location to other pod using emptyDir volumeMount.

I am getting standard stdout & stderr in my ELF stack - dashboard. How do I capture my custom logs?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: elk
  namespace: default
  labels:
    k8s-app: elk-logging
    version: v1
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: elk-logging
        version: v1
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: elk
        image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:elasticsearch
        env:
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "cp-os-logging-dashboard"
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
            value: "http"
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: logs
          mountPath: /home/services/*/logs/
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: logs
        hostPath:
          path: /home/services/*/logs/
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

I have experimented with volume host-path's, emptyDir and other varieties prior to asking question here. All I want is access my application logs from daemonset. I was able to do that without daemonset.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes will send all the logs to nodes /var/log etc. You need hostPath volume for fluentd daemoset to pick it up and send to your logger. [EmptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir), as the name suggest, will be empty when the pod is scheduled to a node.

```
...
...
volumes:
- name: varlog
  hostPath:
    path: /var/log
- name: varlibdockercontainers
  hostPath:
    path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

Check https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/kubernetes-fluentd and https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/blob/master/fluentd-daemonset-elasticsearch.yaml for more info.

Comment: thank you. I have already those in place and tried then now. still not working.

Comment: Can you share your daemonset yaml?